# Preserving image size in matplotlib mp4 animation output

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

While working on an animation with matplotlib I imported an image using imread(). The output is working well using plt.show() but when I try to save the animation to an mp4 file using anim.save() I got a different output with two main issues:

- The image size is changed
- There is a line appears at the start of the video and it in the plt.show(), as I need, it is plotted after plotting some other elements.

plt.show() pic: [image]

mp4 screen: [image]

My source code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from decimal import Decimal
from matplotlib.offsetbox import (TextArea, DrawingArea, OffsetImage,
                                  AnnotationBbox)


g = 9.8
v = 3.5
theta = 45.0 * np.pi / 180.0
t = 2 * v * np.sin(theta) / g
t = np.arange(0, 0.05, 0.01)
x = np.arange(0, 0.05, 0.01)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xlim(-1, 3)
plt.ylim(0, 3)

ax.set_ylabel('')

# Turn off tick labels
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_xticklabels(['','',0,50,100,150,200,250,300])
plt.xlabel('Distance (meter)')
plt.ylabel('Height (meter)')
plt.plot([0,0],[0,1.2],lw='3',color='k')


patch = plt.Circle((5, -5), 0.05, fc='b',zorder=6,)

v_=0
x_,y_,Xp,Yp_=[],[],[],[]
i=0
flag=0
while True:
    ff=True
    y__=Decimal((v * np.sin(theta) * (x + i /100.0) - (0.5) * g * (x + i / 100.0)**2)[0])+Decimal(1.2)
    if y__ < flag:
        if i%3==0:ff=False
    if ff:
        x_.append(Decimal(v * np.cos(theta) * (t + i /100.0)[0]))
        y_.append(Decimal((v * np.sin(theta) * (x + i /100.0) - (0.5) * g * (x + i / 100.0)**2)[0])+Decimal(1.2))

    flag=y__
    if y__<0:
        x_.append(Decimal(v * np.cos(theta) * (t + i /100.0)[0]))
        y_.append(Decimal((v * np.sin(theta) * (x + i /100.0) - (0.5) * g * (x + i / 100.0)**2)[0])+Decimal(1.2))
        break

    i+=1


Ax=[v/10 for v in range(5)]
Ay=[v+1.2 for v in Ax]
Ax= Ax[::-1]+Ax
Ay= [1.2]*len(Ay)+Ay

plt.plot(x_,y_,lw='1',color='k',linestyle='--', dashes=(2, 2))
dashed_c, = ax.plot([], [], color='r',zorder=4,lw='1',linestyle='--', dashes=(2, 2))


ax.annotate('$45^{\circ}$', xy=(0,1.2), xytext=(15, 5),color='b',
                textcoords='offset points',ha='left')

ax.annotate('$v_0=%d$'%(v*10), xy=(-.25,1.5), xytext=(15, 5),color='b',
                textcoords='offset points',ha='left')

text = plt.text(-.5, 2.5, "Distance $= \cdots$ meter")

anim_y = ax.annotate('$y=?$ m', xy=(-10,-10), xytext=(20, 10),color='b',ha='right',
            textcoords='offset points', family='sans serif', style='italic',zorder=5)


Y=[n/10 for n in range(13)]
X=[-.5]*len(Y)

xy = (0, .612)

arr_img = plt.imread("b_.png" )

imagebox = OffsetImage(arr_img)
imagebox.image.axes = ax

ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, xy,
                    xycoords='data',
                    pad=0
                    )
ax.add_artist(ab)


def init():
    patch.center = (5, 5)
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    return

t = [str(n) for n in range(i+75)]
def animate(i):


    if i <= 30:
        pass
    if 30<i<=40:
        dashed_c.set_data(Ax,Ay)

    if 40<i<135 and i-40 < len(x_)-1:
        i-=40
        x, y = patch.center
        x = x_[i]
        y = y_[i]
        patch.center = (x, y)

        text.set_text("Distance =  {0} m".format(str((round(x_[i],2 )+Decimal('.02'))*100).strip('00').strip('.')))
        i+=40
    if 135<i<149:
        i-=135
        HE.set_data(X[:int(i)], Y[:int(i)])
        i+=135
    if 149<i<153:
        i-=149
        anim_y.xy = (-.75,.6)
        plt.pause(1)
        anim_y.xy = (-10,-10)
        plt.pause(1)
        i+=149
    if i==153:
        i-=149
        anim_y.xy = (-.75,.6)
        plt.pause(5)


    return

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                               init_func=init,
                               frames=i+75,
                               interval=20,
                               repeat=False)
HE, = plt.plot([],[],lw='1',color='k',linestyle='--', dashes=(2, 2))

ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
plt.close()


Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=25, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=900)
anim.save('./sample.mp4', writer=writer,dpi=192)
```

What I need is to save the same output that appears on the GUI window to the mp4.

b_.png file: [image]

Comment: Although your question is well written, it would help if you could provide `b_.png` so that your question would be a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what happens if you specify `dpi=192` to `plt.subplots()`?

Comment: The question is more: Why do you specify a different dpi for the saved animation than for the figure. This will lead to images having a different size; if this is not wanted, there should be no reason to do it.

Comment: I try various values for the dpi depending on the animation itself in order to enhance the mp4 quality. Another thing I already changed the DPI of the file b_.png before inserting it using illustrator. What confuses me is that the video output differs from the plot.show() output. Can you please explain why would that happen? Plus I'v already tried to use the default dpi value and the output still the same.